# Pokemon Go 0.35.0 on ZenFone 5

Tags: gps, asus-zenfone-5, pokemon-go

Sometimes my character won't move even though i am moving in real life. Everything is fine, gps is working fine, sometimes my character just stand there and I can spin the pokestop for hours. But the problem is i can't hatch my egg sometimes, is that bug or problem for zenfone 5? Or is that any ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible issues**
 1) You did not provide all the necessary permissions requested by the app to function properly.
 - you need to go to the settings -> apps and check the permissions.

2) Your network might be an issue.
- check the data transfer rate while in the game, and see if there is data being transferred when this happens. if not more than 2kbps then there is a high possibility of this being the cause.

Comment: My phone is having android L which grants all the permissions requested by app as default when installing. So it might be the latter which cause the problem. Is there any way to check data transfer rate while in the game?

Comment: basically i would not recommend installing a seperate app for this purpose, but [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter.lite&hl=en) might help.

and i guess android L does not have an inbuilt data traffic monitor like android marshmallow.